# when creating pdf with delphi how to give line break?

Tags: delphi, pdf, pdf-generation

I am creating my own pdf with delphi. I am using Tj,BT and ET commands but I can't give line break. Which command I have to use for this line break problem or how to give line break? any link,reference or help?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how this relates to Delphi (which PDF component are you using?), but from what I know about postscript as used by PDF, the font data describes the width of each character, which is used for horizontal progression, but vertical progression is done with the `TL` and the `'` command. See [the PDF reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive.html) section 5.3.2

Comment: **TL** and **'** (or **"** or **Tj** + **T***) is one option. Often you see explicit moves instead. Or even new text matrices set for each line.